# É possível saber de onde se originou uma execução sql no SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Há uma situação que acredito que será de muita importância para mim, que é a de saber a origem de um comando sql no SQL SERVER.

Suponha que acidentalmente, um usuário tenha executado um comando qualquer. Então preciso saber quem executou tal comando.

Existe algum jeito de saber quem foi o executor de tal comando, o dia e horário e outras informações relativas ao comando através unicamente de comando sql?

Comment: Pelo log de consultas talvez dê para saber de qual maquina/ip veio o comando ai vc identifica o suspeito.

Comment: sabe me informar que informações eu pegaria desse suspeito?

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27525859/2236741

Comment: Acho que o ip mesmo, imagine se todo mundo usa o mesmo login de admin ... não adianta de nada saber qual usuário foi.

Comment: A funcionalidade SQL Server Audit foi lançada no SQL Server 2008. Eu fiquei interessado e ia fazer um teste, entretanto, o SQL que tenho aqui é 2005. Mais informações: http://bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/30/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/

Comment: estou olhando esse link que você mandou, é exatamente o que estou buscando, só quero entender tudo o que foi respondido lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta ativar o log das queries.

Então faria as consultas nas tabelas de logs do `sys`.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT 
c.connect_time,
s.login_time,
s.host_name,
s.login_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s ON c.session_id = s.session_id
```

*A query acima é meramente ilustrativa. Adapte-a conforma a sua necessidade.

Obviamente que deve existir uma rígida hierarquia de acesso as funções do banco de dados. Se você fornecer um mesmo usuário para todos usarem, nunca vai saber quem executou o quê.

Normalmente controla-se atividades de usuário pelo aplicativo. Todavia, caso exista usuários com permissões com acesso direto ao banco de dados, como não há um aplicativo intermediário, terá que fazer o log usando o recurso de log do próprio SGDB.

Comment: Blz, mas isso independe de onde esses usuários estiverem? por exemplo, pense em dois casos. Um caso que estejam todos na mesma rede, e outro caso que estejam cada um em suas casas, por exemplo. Haverá diferenças?

Comment: Isso é do próprio SGDB. O log das execuções é salvo nas tabelas do `sys`, indepentende de qual meio for a origem da execução. O local onde está o usuário é indiferente.

Comment: Daniel Omine, só teve uma coisa que não entendi na sua query. Que é a parte que você pode para eu adaptá-la conforme a minha necessidade. Onde eu colocaria o comando que procuro saber. Por exemplo, quero saber quem deu um truncate ontem, onde eu colocaria isso ali na query que você passou?

Comment: Busque nas documentações. O exemplo acima mostra basicamente nome do usuário, data e hora que executou e tempo de execução, tal como o host. Dá uma olhada no seu banco de dados nas tabelas do SYS para obter outros dados que queira consultar.

Comment: executei aqui e vi as informações. Em rede elas me parecerem muito úteis, vou dar uma olhada na documentação e testar com esses da tabela do SYS

Comment: Daniel, após pesquisar, verifiquei isso aqui hoje. https://sqlship.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/how-to-capture-delete-and-truncate-t-sql-using-database-audit-specification/ 
Tem conhecimento sobre esse audit?

Comment: Sim, são ferramentas de auditoria do sql server. Também úteis para o que precisa.

Comment: Daniel estou para aceitar sua resposta, mas me esclareça uma coisa: o ip na forma dos números: Ex.: 192.198.162.0, não deveria aparecer no resultado dessa consulta quando você "s.host_name"?

Comment: O host name não tem a ver com o host do cliente. É meramente o host name pelo qual o usuário se conectou. Por exemplo `%, localhost, ip local do server`. Entendeu? É o host definido na string de conexão.

Comment: Ah sim, agora ficou mais claro! Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

O SQL Server não provê solução para isso. Existe o Trace, mas esse só salva as informações quando requisitado.

A melhor forma de auditar alteração de dados na sua base é via trigger.